# how to set opitional on click listener for edit text

Tags: java, android, onclick

hello i want to set onClickListener that will do 3 things
 1. onClick 
 2. onChange
 3. onRelease
what is the command that i need to do?

```
layout.editText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                }
            });
```

I'm learning java and i am new on this programing.. so sorry for the question..

Comment: The `onChange` part is a popular question around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read :

- [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29)
- [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)
- [setOnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29)